# What will be complexity of reccurance relation : T (n) = 0.5T (n/2) + 1/n

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, relation, recurrence

How to calculate the complexity of this case since master method fails for a<1?

Comment: Since `T(n)` is expressed in terms of `T(n/2)`, I'd say the complexity will be something like O(log n); one needs log n steps to get from `n` to 1.

Comment: The scale factor of 0.5 means that `T(n)` decreases with increasing `n`, so the actual complexity is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve the recurrence relation below:

```
T(n) = (1/2) * T(n/2) +  (1/n)
T(n/2) = (1/2) * T(n/4) + (1/(2/n))
Therefore:
T(n) = (1/4) * T(n/4) + (1/n) + (1/n)  Notice the pattern.
In overall:
T(n) = (1/2^k) * T(n/2^k) + (1/n)*k
2^k = n   -->   k = log(n)
T(n) = (1/n) * T(1) + (1/n)*log(n)
T(n) = (log(n) + c)/n    c = constant
T(n) ~ log(n)/n
```

Notice that as `n` goes to infinity, total number of operations goes to zero.
Recall the formal definition of Big-Oh notation:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) means there are positive constants c and k, such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ k.

`T(n)` = `O(1)` since 0 <= T(n) <= c*1 for all n >= k for some k>0 and c>0.